# in xcode6 gold master, using objc_msgSend now throws a syntax error saying the number of arguments is wrong

Tags: ios, xcode6

```
 id<MyProtocol> topLayoutGuideObj = objc_msgSend(viewController, @selector(myselector));
```

"Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 2"

However, the function signature for objc_msgSend looks like this:

```
#if !OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES
OBJC_EXPORT void objc_msgSend(void /* id self, SEL op, ... */ )
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
OBJC_EXPORT void objc_msgSendSuper(void /* struct objc_super *super, SEL op, ... */ )
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
#else
/** 
 * Sends a message with a simple return value to an instance of a class.
 * 
 * @param self A pointer to the instance of the class that is to receive the message.
 * @param op The selector of the method that handles the message.
 * @param ... 
 *   A variable argument list containing the arguments to the method.
 * 
 * @return The return value of the method.
 * 
 * @note When it encounters a method call, the compiler generates a call to one of the
 *  functions \c objc_msgSend, \c objc_msgSend_stret, \c objc_msgSendSuper, or \c objc_msgSendSuper_stret.
 *  Messages sent to an object’s superclass (using the \c super keyword) are sent using \c objc_msgSendSuper; 
 *  other messages are sent using \c objc_msgSend. Methods that have data structures as return values
 *  are sent using \c objc_msgSendSuper_stret and \c objc_msgSend_stret.
 */
OBJC_EXPORT id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

The arguments are "void" or variadic ?! I don't understand how I'm supposed to call this.

Comment: Curious why you don't simply call `[viewController mySelector];`.

Comment: fair question. I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to fix it - and change it as little as possible. However, I may end up doing just that

Comment: iOs 8 GM and Xcode 6 GM are under NDA, try Apple developers forum or Apple tech support.

Comment: @A-Live They are under permissive NDA and it is allowed to post questions and talk about it outside of Apple ecosystem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See just a few lines above you referred.

```
 /* 
  * ...
  *
  * These functions must be cast to an appropriate function pointer type 
  * before being called. 
  */
```

You can call it like:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

id<MyProtocol> topLayoutGuideObj = ((id (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(viewController, @selector(myselector));
```

OR

```
id (*typed_msgSend)(id, SEL) = (void *)objc_msgSend;
id<MyProtocol> topLayoutGuideObj = typed_msgSend(viewController, @selector(myselector));
```

Comment: Apparently, the reason why this shows up in Xcode 6 is because the warning "Enable strict checking of objc_msgSend calls" is now enabled by default, and switched on by default when you open an old project and "Update project to recommended settings".

Comment: A similar fix is required for objc_msgSendSuper().  Following rintaro's second example, the answer is:

id (*typed_msgSendSuper)(struct objc_super *, SEL, ...) = (void *)objc_msgSendSuper ;
returnValue = typed_msgSendSuper(&yourSuperStruct, yourSelector, yourFirstArg, ...) ;

Answer (score 11):

I have checked it out, the main problem was as @Jerry Krinock said in comment of accepted answer;

1. Go to your project Build Settings
2. Search for objc_msgSend
3. Set its value to "No" instead of "Yes"

Comment: Don't do that.   The warning exists for a reason;   without type-casting objc_msgSend() to the specifically typed set of parameters you want to pass, it isn't going to work on some ABIs.   Varargs is not the same as an explicitly typed parameter list.

Comment: As an example for what @bbum says, when you pass a `char` (or `BOOL`, which typedefs to char) via varargs, it is promoted to an int, which it isn't if you typecast the function to the type it actually has. A regular call doesn't promote chars either, so if you turn off the warning, all you get is you don't realize when you're passing random garbage to your function.