# Type of self and delegate for casting to fix objc_msgSend wrong number of arguments error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an iPad app that I wrote a few years ago using Greg Coombs’ [IntelligentSplitViewController](https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController) which allows one to produce a layout similar to the rotatable UITabBarController in an iPhone app. The recent release of iOS 10 broke this in a way that has [previously been described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852079/in-xcode6-gold-master-using-objc-msgsend-now-throws-a-syntax-error-saying-the-n) for an earlier version on this list: objc_msgSend gives an error message that *there are a finite number of arguments whereas it is expecting 0.*

The answer to this by @rintaro was to perform a type cast to another method (typed_msgSend) to use instead of objc_msgSend. In response to the other poster’s code with *two* arguments this was:

```
id (*typed_msgSend)(id, SEL) = (void *)objc_msgSend;
```

Greg’s code is a little more complex, and given my weakness in objective-C I am having difficulty doing something similar to his code. (Greg, unfortunately, has been ill and has ceased supporting this.) The details are as follows:

```
- (void)willRotate:(NSNotification*)notification
{
...
   if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toOrientation)) 
   {
      @try 
     {
         UIPopoverController *popover = [super valueForKey:@"_hiddenPopoverController"];
         objc_msgSend(theDelegate, @selector(splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:), self, master, button, popover);
     ...
```

So the question is what are the data types of the *six* arguments? My attempts were:

1. theDelegate — *unsure* — tried ‘id’ or ‘id<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>’ (from its declaration)
2. @selector... — SEL (by analogy with answer)
3. self — *really don’t know* — tried ‘id’
4. master — UIViewController* (from declaration)
5. button — UIBarButtonItem* (from declaration)
6. popover — UIPopoverController* (from declaration)

This builds, but crashes in main after the splash screen. It may, of course, be crashing for some other reason, but unless I am sure that I have done the type cast right, I can’t know. (How I wish this were Java.)

Comment: Why are you using `objc_msgSend` instead of standard method calling syntax?

Comment: @maddy — Because that's the code in the class I obtained that solved my original problem. I didn't write it.

Comment: Then replace the inappropriate call to `objc_msgSend` with a normal method call and eliminate your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void (*my_objc_msgSend)(id, SEL, id, id, id, id) = (__typeof(my_objc_msgSend))objc_msgSend;  
my_objc_msgSend(theDelegate, @selector(splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:), self, master, button, popover);
```

in objc, `id` is a point of struct. any object (which class inherit from `NSObject`) can use `id` instead.

please post the log if still crash.

After iOS 9, `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` is deprecated, you should use `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately  it still crashes. The relevant (I hope) part of the crash log was: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<IntelligentSplitViewController 0x7fe32ac09940> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _hiddenPopoverController.'"

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with the casting. It is occurring in the viewWillAppear method where there is a similar sort of thing:  UIView *popoverSuperview = ((UIPopoverController*)[super valueForKey:@"_hiddenPopoverController"]).contentViewController.view.superview; There is a comment that it is part of a bugfix hack, which suggests I am going to have to strip the whole thing down and do it differently. Building on too many hacks I don't understand and continuing to use deprecated methods would seem a bad way to go.

Comment: crash is not cause by `objc_msgSend` (`splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:`).   the `IntelligentSplitViewController` lib use a private ivar named `_hiddenPopoverController`, but in iOS 10 it was removed. so KVO cause a undefined key error.

Comment: private api may rejected by appstore, and it may changed when new ios release.

Comment: Thanks again. I really appreciate your help. It may be that I should post a new question, but I am still rather unclear what happened. I gather that one can declare ivars in the @implementation so does the mere inclusion of _hiddenPopoverController make it a private ivar? (I don't see it anywhere else). If so, what has changed in ios 10 to break this? It was the installed app that worked on ios9 that broke on 10. The app didn't change. And is there anything I can do about it? I realize it might not get through the store, but there was always that risk before.

Comment: Kill the cast.  There is absolutely no reason for it even if it isn't the source of your problem.

Comment: apple hide the implementation so `_hiddenPopoverController ` is not visible to developer, when iOS 10 release, apple may rename this ivar or remove it so your can't use kvo to get it. usually, we should only use the public method and property of a class. if you really want to use it, you should do some dirty hack on iOS 10. maybe the tool `FLEX` can help you.

Comment: I think I can focus a little. objc_msgSend works and invokes the correct object method. However, following parameters (after self and selector) are not passed correctly to the method. Tried casting them to  id, instanceType, void *, and the actual type they are, to no avail. Within the object method - they are garbage. Attempt to access them - you crash. Same code works flawlessly when built with iOS 6 to iOS 9 SDK - fails with iOS10. Maybe we need to specify the alignment of parameters to the compiler? Where? how? Where is a release note to tell us that ObjC runtime changed its behavior?